# Local Variables are not showing in VS Code while debugging

Tags: c++, json, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am really sorry if this question is been asked before, but I couldn't get a solution.
The following is my launch.json and Adding a picture as well. And I am really sure about it that the Program file path and debugger path is correct. The main issue is that I can not see the values of local variables even though I have marked breakpoints.

{

```
"configurations": [

{

    "name": "(gdb) Launch",

    "type": "cppdbg",

    "request": "launch",

    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",//Program File path is correct

    "args": [],

    "stopAtEntry": true,

    "cwd": "${fileDirname}",

    "environment": [],

    "externalConsole": false,

    "MIMode": "gdb",

    "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",//And I am sure this is correct as well

    "setupCommands": [

        {

            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",

            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",

            "ignoreFailures": true

        },

        {

            "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",

            "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",

            "ignoreFailures": true

        }

    ]

}

]
```

}[image: As we can see the registers variables, but can not see the local variable which I've used in my program.]

Comment: Are you compiling with debugger symbols? -g3 I believe.

Comment: I can not understand what exactly needed to be changed, According to you. I will try that as well.